# End of Line Word Counting (C++)

Tags: c++

I need to create a program that reads in a file, counts the words inside of it, and lists unique words with their frequency. The program considers any series of characters without spaces a word (so things like "hello." "hello" and ",.?" are all different words). I am having difficulty with using an if statement and adding a word at the end of the line to my word count. It counts the words that have spaces after them but not '/n'. This is the code I have for counting the words:

```
in.get(last);
in.get(current);
while(!in.eof())
{
    if((current == ' ' && last != ' ') || (current == '/n' && last != ' ' && last != '/n'))
        count++;
    last = current;
    in.get(current);
}
```

Comment: How about '\n' instead.

Comment: Turning on compiler warnings would have helped in this case.

Comment: Also, you are always only comparing the current word to the last word.  Just thought I would point that out.  It sounds like you want to compare each word to each other word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a painful way to do it...  You are better off reading strings, which are automatically  delimited by whitespace.

```
string word;
map<string,int> freq;

while( in >> word ) {
    freq[word]++;
}
```

Note that in the example you gave, you used `'/n'`, which should be `'\n'`.  In my example, you don't even need it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use STL's for the assignment. Thank you though! Silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I would createca map,http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/, and if the word exists increment frequency otherwise add the word to the map.

This way you quickly check if the word exists, to have a unique list.